# Nested grouping with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given a database the form of

```
[
{ gender: "m", age: 1, name: "A" },
{ gender: "f", age: 2, name: "B" },
{ gender: "m", age: 3, name: "C" },
{ gender: "f", age: 1, name: "D" },
{ gender: "m", age: 2, name: "E" },
{ gender: "f", age: 3, name: "F" },
{ gender: "m", age: 1, name: "G" },
{ gender: "f", age: 2, name: "H" },
{ gender: "m", age: 3, name: "I" },
{ gender: "f", age: 1, name: "J" }
]
```

I want to first group by age and secondly group by gender so that I get a nested result looking something like

```
[{
    _id: "1",
    children: [
        { _id: "f" },
        { _id: "m" }
    ]
}, {
    _id: "2",
    children: [
        { _id: "f" },
        { _id: "m" }
    ]
}, {
    _id: "3",
    children: [
        { _id: "f" },
        { _id: "m" }
    ]
}]
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
db.example.aggregate(
{ $group: { _id: "$age", children: { $addToSet: {
    age: "$age", gender: "$gender", name: "$name"
}}}},
{ $group: { _id: "$children.gender"}}
)
```

But this returns an `{_id: null}` as its result. Is this possible and in case yes, how?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Something like this should do it;

```
db.example.aggregate( 
  { 
    $group: { 
      _id:   { age: "$age", gender: "$gender" }, 
      names: { $addToSet: "$name" } 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: { age: "$_id.age" }, 
      children: { $addToSet: { gender: "$_id.gender", names:"$names" } } 
    } 
  } 
)
```

...which gives the result;

```
{
  "_id" : {
    "age" : 1
  },
  "children" : [
    { "gender" : "m", "names" : [ "G", "A" ] },
    { "gender" : "f", "names" : [ "J", "D" ] }
  ]
}, 
...
```

If you want the age as `_id` as in your example, just replace the second grouping's `_id` by;

```
_id: "$_id.age",
```

Comment: I was looking for this, as I failed all the time trying to recreate, but one more question how to I count the gender? How many times a gender appears for every age?