# Group/Aggregate fields together

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a csv file which I imported into MongoDB, it has the following structure:

[image]

I want to group this with the start as id, and all the other fields as childs of that, like such:

```
  "_id" : "A" {
            "destination" : B {
                "duration" : 5
                "duration" : 3
                "duration" : 6
            }
            "destination" : C {
                "duration" : 10
            }
  }
  "_id" : "B" {
            "destination" : A {
                "duration" : 4
            }
  }
```

I understand the basics of the aggregation command of MongoDB, I tried this which is based on Yogesh's answer:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{   "$group": {
    "_id": "$start",
    "Trips": {
        "$push": {
            "Destination" : "$destination",
            "Duration"     : "$duration"
        }
    }
    }
}],{allowDiskUse:true}).pretty()
```

My question is how I can also group duration into there. Right now, for 2 'trips' from A to B, there are 2 entries like such:

```
    {   "Destination": B,
        "Duration": 5
    },
    {
        "EndStationID": B,
        "Duration": 3
    }
```

How can I also combine those into a structure like this:

```
    {  "Destination": B {
            "Duration": 5,
            "Duration": 3
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your CSV structure I created following collection

```
{ "start" : "A", "destination" : "B", "duration" : 5 }
{ "start" : "A", "destination" : "B", "duration" : 3 }
{ "start" : "A", "destination" : "B", "duration" : 6 }
{ "start" : "B", "destination" : "A", "duration" : 4 }
```

First you should `group` start and destination fields and then push duration into array so aggregation query as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "start": "$start",
        "dest": "$destination"
    },
    "duration": {
        "$push": {
            "duration": "$duration"
        }
    }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "_id": "$_id.start",
    "destination": "$_id.dest",
    "duration": 1
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using partially your approach in combination with the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772156/nested-grouping-with-mongodb